# Noun for something important

Tags: single-word-requests, north-american-english

Is there a noun for something important, something that plays a big role in a given situation? The term *game changer* doesn't fit the description in my opinion (because it implies the important thing being something introduced recently), and the term *biggie* seems kind of rare and informal.

Comment: It depends on the situation and context as well. If you could give an example, we could try to find the best word also. Even "everything" gives this meaning. Ex: "She is everything to me."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the crux, linchpin, or keystone, depending on the situation/usage.